# HTML content to a string with regular expressions

Tags: java, html, regex

I need to compose an email body and have user name password atributes to be added of every user to it. For now i have the html content in a string and im trying to have string formatter to replace the user name and password for the respective user. How ever I am having trouble having the html content in a single string and also get the mapping of diferent users to be changed accordingly.

code snipet

```
String regEmailBody =
        "<div>
            + "successfully registered for the system. <br>Your username " 
            + "is[@email_placeholder].<br>Your temporary password is <b>"
            + "@sysGeneratedPW_placeholder!</b><br>Please login to the system to reset your password, "
            + "click on the button below.<br></p></div>"; 


    regEmailBody.replaceFirst("@name_placeholder", name); 
    regEmailBody.replaceAll("@userEmail", emailAdd);
```

Comment: This things are [trickier than you might think](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/471272).

Answer (score 1):

Strings in java are immutable. In your code, you are producing new strings with replaced parts, but you are not storing them anywhere.

```
regEmailBody = regEmailBody.replaceFirst("@name_placeholder", name);
```

(the example code are also missing a " after the div, and the placeholder strings does not correspond with what you're trying to replace.)